# Set all column values based on condition existing in one row using Snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Working on a view in Snowflake and based certain criteria I want to set the Pass/Fail column for all rows to "Pass" if a certain output is reached.  Example (below)for a give Item number/ Plant combination, where the condition is met for one row, I would like to set all rows to "Pass"

Here is my case statement as is:   I'm Having trouble getting this scenario to "Pass" for all rows

```
case
    when
        ((case
            when 'PIRStatus' is null
            then 'PIR-Missing'
            else 'PIR-Exists'
        end)='PIR-Exists' 
    and "FixedVendor" = 'X' 
    and (case 
            when "SLStatus" = 'SL-Exists'
        then 1 
        else 2
    end) = 1)
then 'Pass'
else 'Fail'
end as "Pass/Fail"
```

PIRStatus    Vendor BlockedVendor FixedVendor SLStatus  Pass/Fail
**PIR-Exists 12547                    X       SL-Exists   Pass**
PIR-Exists   85996                            SL-Missing  Fail
PIR-Exists   54788                            SL-Missing  Fail

This is based on a given Item/ Plant combination, as long as any row says pass then I want the other rows to Pass as well

Comment: Do you mean update rows with the same Item/ Plant combination, rather than all rows in the table? If you do then you need to show the table definition(s) that includes all relevant columns. Please all provide sample data and the result you want to achieve (that may be what is after your code but the way it is formatted makes it indecipherable)

Comment: Yes only the rows with the same item / plant combo..

Comment: OK - so we would need to see the table definition(s) that show these two columns (Item and plant) plus all the other columns you've referenced in the code. As I stated in my previous comment, you need to also provide some sample data and the result you want to achieve based on that data

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to use a correlated subquery, which I find is best written with a CTE like this:

```
WITH CTE_CONDITION AS (
  SELECT 
    id, 
    case when (
      (
        case when 'PIRStatus' is null then 'PIR-Missing' else 'PIR-Exists' end
      )= 'PIR-Exists' 
      and "FixedVendor" = 'X' 
      and (
        case when "SLStatus" = 'SL-Exists' then 1 else 2 end
      ) = 1
    ) then 'Pass' else 'Fail' end as "Pass/Fail" 
  FROM 
    table
) 
SELECT 
  * ,
CASE WHEN EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM CTE_CONDITION WHERE "Pass/Fail" = 'Pass' AND table.id = CTE_CONDITION.id) 
    THEN 'This ID Passes At Least Somewhere'
    ELSE 'This ID never passes' 
    END as DOES_THIS_EVER_PASS
FROM table
```

The thing to remember using `EXISTS` is that the `SELECT` portion doesn't really matter (thus, `SELECT 1`) but it is the `WHERE` clause that connects the table itself to CTE_CONDITION.

You might even clean this up by creating CTE_PASS and CTE_FAIL and putting conditions in the `WHERE` clauses, to compartmentalize the logic and avoid that messy `CASE` statement.

Thus, you could accomplish the same thing with something like:

```
WITH CTE_PASS AS (
  SELECT id
  FROM table
  WHERE {conditions that mean a pass}
) 
SELECT 
  * ,
CASE WHEN EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM CTE_PASS WHERE table.id = CTE_CONDITION.id) 
     THEN 'This ID Passes At Least Somewhere'
     ELSE 'This ID never passes' 
     END as DOES_THIS_EVER_PASS
FROM table
```

Comment: Seems like this is setting ALL values to Pass and not considering Item/ Plant combination

Comment: @JohnHughes I can't tell from the details in the question what other plant / item conditions you want to match on, but you would simply add those conditions in the EXISTS clause, like "AND table.plant_id = CTE_CONDITION.plant_id" as well as add whatever IDs you want to match in the CTE as well

Comment: Thanks!  Added the Item/Plant to the case statement:

CASE WHEN EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM CTE_CONDITION WHERE "Pass/Fail" = 'Pass' and mat."MaterialNumber" = CTE_CONDITION."MaterialNumber" and mat."PLantMM" = CTE_CONDITION."PLantMM") 
    THEN 'Pass'
    ELSE 'Fail' 
 END as "Pass/Fail"

seems to work now, thanks again!!

Comment: Still analyzing the data, will post the answer when I know we are 100%.  Thanks again guys!